# Integral involving the Q-Function

Tags: integration

Would anyone help me solving this integral

$$ \int_{-\infty}^n(\exp(\frac {(x+a)^2}{2} )  Q(c-x) dx  $$

where $ Q(x) = \frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{x} ^{\infty}\exp(-\frac{v^2}{2})dv $ 
$ a,c,n >0$

Please.
Thanks

Comment: Take the derivative of your integral wrt. $c$. Then the terms with $x{^2}$ in the exponential cancel and you can do the $c$-integral.

Comment: Dear @Urgje , would you please guide me through it since I am not a mathematician, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right. Here are the details. But check for calculational
mistakes!
\begin{equation*}
I(c)=\int_{-\infty }^{n}dx\exp [\frac{(x+a)^{2}}{2}]Q(c-x),\;Q(c-x)=\frac{1}{%
\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{c-x}^{\infty }dv\exp [-\frac{v^{2}}{2}]
\end{equation*}
We note that $Q(c-x)\overset{c\rightarrow \infty }{\longrightarrow }0$.
Since $-\infty \leqslant x\leqslant n$ we have $+\infty \geqslant
c-x\geqslant c-n$ and
\begin{eqnarray*}
Q(c-x) &=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{c-x}^{\infty }dv\exp [-\frac{v^{2}}{2}%
]\leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp [-\frac{(c-n)^{2}}{4}%
]\int_{c-x}^{\infty }dv\exp [-\frac{v^{2}}{4}] \\
I(c) &\leqslant &\int_{-\infty }^{n}dx\exp [\frac{(x+a)^{2}}{2}]\frac{1}{%
\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp [-\frac{(c-n)^{2}}{4}]\int_{c-x}^{\infty }dv\exp [-\frac{%
v^{2}}{4}] \\
&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp [-\frac{(c-n)^{2}}{4}]\int_{-\infty
}^{n}dx\exp [\frac{(x+a)^{2}}{2}]\int_{c-x}^{\infty }dv\exp [-\frac{v^{2}}{4}%
]
\end{eqnarray*}
so
\begin{equation*}
I(c)\overset{c\rightarrow \infty }{\longrightarrow }0
\end{equation*}
Next we differentiate

\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{c}Q(c-x) &=&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp [-\frac{(c-x)^{2}}{2}] \\
\partial _{c}I(c) &=&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{n}dx\exp [\frac{%
(x+a)^{2}}{2}]\exp [-\frac{(c-x)^{2}}{2}] \\
&=&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{n}dx\exp [\frac{1}{2}%
\{(x+a)^{2}-(x-c)^{2}\}] \\
&=&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{n}dx\exp [\frac{1}{2}%
\{2ax+a^{2}+2cx-c^{2}] \\
&=&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp [a^{2}-c^{2}]\int_{-\infty }^{n}dx\exp
[(a+c)x] \\
&=&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp [a^{2}-c^{2}]\left[ \frac{\exp [(a+c)x]}{a+c}%
\right] _{-\infty }^{n} \\
&=&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp [a^{2}-c^{2}]\frac{\exp [(a+c)n]}{a+c} \\
&=&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp [a^{2}+an]\frac{1}{a+c}\exp [-c^{2}+cn]
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus
\begin{eqnarray*}
I(\infty )-I(c) &=&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp [a^{2}+an]\int_{c}^{\infty }dw%
\frac{1}{a+w}\exp [-w^{2}+wn] \\
I(c) &=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp [a^{2}+an]\int_{c}^{\infty }dw\frac{1}{a+w%
}\exp [-w^{2}+wn]
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus we are left with a single integral but I do not know if it can be
expressed in terms of standard functions.